# Isotope and jquery.cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-cookie

I've got an jquery isoptope that I filter with checkboxes. The value of the checkboxes are retrieved with jquery cookie and I want to set the initial filter using the values of the checkboxes. I've made a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qdzcP/10/

I'm creating a new variable

```
var initfilter = [];
$checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
  initfilter.push( this.value );
});
initfilter = initfilter.join(', ');
```

and then loading the variable as a filter when I load isotope

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    filter: 'initfilter'
});
```

However it seems that the filter that initialises is not correct. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are assigning it a string and not the variable. try `filter: initfilter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning filter a string value of `initfilter`.  Remove the quotes to use the variable

```
filter: initfilter
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/RNB8T/)**

Comment: @adnan stuff like that happens when you stare at code too long :P